# R lang: Error in sits_apply(), vctrs_vec_compat(.x, .purrr_user_env): object not found

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, purrr, sits

I am currently working on a project to calculate the NDVI of certain areas using the sits() package in R. However, I am stuck with error output that I cannot interpret in the context of the function.

[In the documentation, the following example is given:](https://e-sensing.github.io/sitsbook/operations-on-data-cubes.html)
:

```
reg_cube <- sits_apply(reg_cube,
  NDVI = (B08 - B04) / (B08 + B04),
  output_dir = "./tempdir/chp5",
  multicores = 4,
  memsize = 12
)
plot(reg_cube, band = "NDVI", palette = "RdYlGn")
```

I slightly adjusted the example to my needs, but the code doesn't run and produces the output which I show in the next step.

```
reg_cube <- sits_apply(reg_cube,
  NDVI = (NIR08 - RED) / (NIR08 + RED),
  output_dir = "/tmp",
  multicores = 8,
  memsize = 60
)
```

The following sample code is supposed to read the shapefile, extract sample points and then calculate the NDVI index using sits_apply() which is documented [here](https://rdrr.io/github/e-sensing/sits.data/man/sits_apply.html) .
However, at reg_cube <-sits_apply(), I receive an error message:

```
Error in vctrs_vec_compat(.x, .purrr_user_env): object 'NDVI' not found
Traceback:

1. sits_get_data(cube = ndvi_cube, samples = samples_lakes, bands = NDVI)
2. .check_bands_in_cube(bands = bands, cube = cube)
3. purrr::map(bands, function(band) {
 .     .check_band_in_cube(band, cube)
 . })
4. map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
5. vctrs_vec_compat(.x, .purrr_user_env)
```

Does anyone have an hint what could have happened here?

```
bangalore_lakes <- st_zm(read_sf("/home/jovyan/PlanetaryComputerExamples/subset_bangalore_south.shp"))

samples_lakes <- sits_get_data(
  cube = reg_cube,
  samples = bangalore_lakes,
  start_date = "2000-01-01", end_date = "2009-12-31",
  n_sam_pol = 5, 
  multicores = 8
)

reg_cube <- sits_apply(reg_cube,
  NDVI = (NIR08 - RED) / (NIR08 + RED),
  output_dir = "/tmp",
  multicores = 8,
  memsize = 60
)


series <- sits_get_data(
  cube = ndvi_cube,
  samples = samples_lakes,
  bands = NDVI
)

plot(series)
```